# Prove that ...$\sqrt[c]{\sqrt[c]{\sqrt[c]{\cdots}}}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis

There's this exercise in my Analysis book I'm having trouble with:

Let $c$ be a positive real constant and define a continued root of $c$ by the sequence {$a_n$} where $$a_1=c$$ and $$a_{n+1}=\sqrt[a_{n}]{c}$$

a) If $c \in (0,1)$, prove that {$a_n$} converges. 
Now I think I got this one right. Clearly, {$a_n$} is bounded below by $0$, and we see that since every term is smaller than $1$, $a_{n+1}=c^d$ where d is $1/{a_n}$ and therefore greater than $1$. So {$a_n$} is decreasing.

b) Evaluate $..\sqrt[c]{\sqrt[c]{c}}$ for $c \in (0,1)$. 
Now this is where I'm stuck. I don't know which conclusions to draw from the above.

c) If $c \in (0,1)$, prove that the series $\sum a_k$ converges.
 Proving that the series converges proves that $..\sqrt[c]{\sqrt[c]{c}}$ converges to $0$.

Perhaps it is of importance that this chapter is (introductory) about series and this section specifically covers the Root-test and the Ratio-test. I expect taht one of the above is supposedly needed somewhere in the exercise but I am unable to succesfully use the tests.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt[a]{\sqrt[b]{c}} = \sqrt[ab]{c}$

Comment: So $a_n=\sqrt[c]{\sqrt[c]{\sqrt[c]{\cdots}}}=c^{1/c^{n-1}}$ and the limit of  $c^{1/c^{n-1}}$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ is 0. Which I believe is the answer to b.

Comment: Also the root test yields: the limit of $\sqrt[n]{c^{1/c^{n-1}}}=c^{1/nc^{n-1}}$   Now since the limit of $nc^{n-1}$ goes to $0$, the power goes to $\infty$ and our limit goes to $0$ too. Since $0<1$ we conclude by the Root test that the series converges.

Comment: @QuestionMaker I think you should check your limit in the first comment.

Comment: @achillehui And I don't see how that helps.

Comment: @SimpleArt Why do you think the limit in my first comment is wrong? As $n \rightarrow \infty$, $c^{n-1} \rightarrow 0$ from above, so $\frac{1}{c^{n-1}} \rightarrow \infty$ and the limit of $c^{1/c^{n-1}} \rightarrow 0$

Comment: @QuestionMaker I'm more likely hinting at that $a_n\ne c^{1/c^{n-1}}$, but instead, $$a_3=\sqrt[a_2]{c}\quad a_2=\sqrt[c]c$$

Comment: Yeah I believe my wrong use of Latex is causing some trouble. I believe you are right in saying I am wrong. Any ideas on how to solve the exercise though? So for question b it actually means just the limit of $a_n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 1):

$c\in(0,1) \implies$ 
$0<a_2 < a_1$

$\{a_n\}$ is monotonically decreasing and bounded below, and therefore convergent.

b) $\{a_n\}$ converges to $0$

$\sum a_n$ converges if $\{a_n\}$ converges to $0$
 and $\lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}| < 1$ (ratio test)

$\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac {c^\frac 1{a_n}}{c^\frac 1{a_{n-1}}} = c^{\frac 1{a_n} - \frac 1{a_{n-1}}}$

since $0<a_n<a_{n-1}$

$\frac 1{a_n} - \frac 1{a_{n-1}}>0$ (and is in fact increasing, itself)

$c^{\frac 1{a_n} - \frac 1{a_{n-1}}}<1$